# Add id to each joomla module if logged in frontend

Tags: php, joomla3.0

i have been searching around the internet for a while and cant get any idea of how i will be able to show the module database id as html attribute id without dealing with the template files.

My first idea was to make a plugin that adds this function to each module loaded but i dont think that is the solution anymore.

I hope some of you can give me some ideas of what methods i should use and if it is possible to do this in some way.

Thank you for your awnsers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into creating what's called a Custom Module Chrome.  To do this does involve creating a file within your template, however.

Is there a reason to not work on the template? The only valid one I can think of is if it is a third party one that gets patched.